# Pandas merge a DataFrame on an exact and partial match

Tags: python, pandas, join

I want to merge two DataFrames on an exact match on the column `Name` and a partial match between `ID` and `String`. Here is an example:

The first DataFrame (df1) looks like this:

```
Name ID    Tag
AAA  1111  XYZ
AAA  1122  DEF
BBB  2222  PQR
BBB  2211  MNL
CCC  3333  STU
CCC  3311  JKL
DDD  4444  ABC
```

The second DataFrame (df2) looks like this;

```
String        Name
aasd1111dasd  AAA
sdf1122sdf    AAA 
sdffgs2222f   BBB
fsfg3333sdf   CCC
sefg4444sdf   DDD
```

What I would like to get to is a join to give the following:

```
String        Name  Tag
aasd1111dasd  AAA   XYZ
sdf1122sdf    AAA   DEF
sdffgs2222f   BBB   PQR
fsfg3333sdf   CCC   STU 
sefg4444sdf   DDD   ABC
```

Comment: What is the logic of the output? Where does sdf1122sdf comes from?

Comment: Seems like a join on ID and the content of `String`

Comment: Even after 5mins reading it, I cannot get the logic of the output

Comment: is there a mistake at the outcome for the second row? If you don't have the second row, it makes sense

Comment: If these are Pandas dataframes, please add the pandas tag.

Comment: Is this the line `sdf1122sdf    AAA` missing from `df2`?

Comment: This has been asked before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642177/python-pandas-dataframe-join-two-dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve is a merge on `Name` and then only keeping rows where `ID` is in the field `String`.

Using:

```py
# df
    Name   ID  Tag
0   AAA  1111  XYZ
1   AAA  1122  DEF
2   BBB  2222  PQR
3   BBB  2211  MNL
4   CCC  3333  STU
5   CCC  3311  JKL
6   DDD  4444  ABC
```

```py
# df2
          String  Name
0   aasd1111dasd   AAA
1     sdf1122sdf   AAA  # This line needed to be added to df2
2    sdffgs2222f   BBB
3    fsfg3333sdf   CCC
4    sefg4444sdf   DDD
```

Merge:

```
m = df.merge(df2)
```

Create a mask:

```
mask = m.apply(lambda x: str(x["ID"]) in x["String"], axis=1)
```

Filter by the mask:

```
m = m[mask][["String", "Name", "Tag"]]
```

Outputs:

```
         String Name  Tag
0  aasd1111dasd  AAA  XYZ
3    sdf1122sdf  AAA  DEF
4   sdffgs2222f  BBB  PQR
6   fsfg3333sdf  CCC  STU
8   sefg4444sdf  DDD  ABC
```